# Push or add to collection in mongoose

Tags: arrays, insert, mongoose

I have a lot of objects I'm saving to Mongoose. They are deep objects.

```
var obj1 = {
  first_name : 'adam',
  last_name: 'smith',
  car : [{
    make: 'honda',
    model: 'civic',
    colors: [{
      name: 'red',
      code: 'ff0000'
    }]
  }]
}
```

Going in to a matching model like so:

```
var Owner = new Schema({
    first_name: String, 
    last_name: String,
    cars:[{
        make: String,
        model: String
        colors: [{
          name: String,
          code: String
        }]
    }]
});
```

Which is all fine and dandy, unless adam has a second record:

```
var obj2 = {
  first_name : 'adam',
  last_name: 'smith',
  car : [{
    make: 'ford',
    model: 'focus',
      colors: [{
        name: 'blue',
        code: '0000ff'
      }]
  }]
}
var obj3 = {
  first_name : 'adam',
  last_name: 'smith',
  car : [{
    make: 'honda',
    model: 'civic',
      colors: [{
        name: 'blue',
        code: '0000ff'
      }]
  }]
}
```

Each overwrites the previous one completely when I do something like:

```
Owner.findOneAndUpdate({first_name:"adam", last_name: "smith"}, obj2, {upsert: true});
```

How do I get mongoose to create a new record when there isn't one, but append to the `car` array when there is? And if the car already exists, append to the colors array?

To make things a little more fun, the structure of the data is not consistent in my case. It is for a given collection, but each of my collections are being set up dynamically, so the model may be many layers deep and have any given keys.

Answer (score 1):

This approaches allows you to push a new element onto an array field

```
db.findOneAndUpdate( 

    {first_name:"adam", last_name: "smith"},
    {   $push: { cars : {
                        make: 'ford',
                        model: 'focus'
                    }
                }
    },

    {   safe: true, 
        upsert: false, 
        new : true
    }
);
```

I feel your pain regarding trying to guess syntax for arbitrarily complex insert/update/deletes ... the world of mongo/mongoose is screaming for a tool to read Schemas/data and let you interactively describe your particulars to synthesize code snippets like above

Comment: Tried this with upsert both true and false, still not saving records. Going to edit question a bit.

Comment: Even calling this after explicitly creating the first-level record, I'm getting nothing stored any deeper. I may have to go back to the drawing board on this one.